# Show that the ratio $x+y:x-y$ is increased by subtracting $y$ from each term.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that the ratio $x+y:x-y$ is increased by subtracting $y$ from each term.

$x+y:x-y=\dfrac{x+y}{x-y} \tag1$

Subtract $y$ from each term:

$x:x-2y=\dfrac{x}{x-2y} \tag2$

Since we are comparing $x$ and $y$, we can assume $k=\dfrac{x}{y} \Rightarrow x=ky$

$(1)= \dfrac{ky+y}{ky-y}, (2)= \dfrac{ky}{ky-2y}$

Subtract $(1)$ from $(2)$ since we are told by the problem statement $(2)$ is bigger:

$\dfrac{(ky)(ky-y)-(ky+y)(ky-2y)}{(ky-y)(ky-2y)} \Rightarrow \dfrac{k^2y^2-ky^2-(k^2y^2-2ky^2+ky^2-2y^2)}{k^2y^2-2ky^2-ky^2+2y^2} \Rightarrow \dfrac{2y^2}{k^2y^2-3ky^2+2y^2}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{2}{k^2-3k+2} \Rightarrow \dfrac{2}{(k-2)(k-1)}$

For $1<k<2; \dfrac{2}{(k-2)(k-1)}<0$ and $\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}>\dfrac{x}{x-2y}$

For $k<1$ and $k>2$; $\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}<\dfrac{x}{x-2y}$

Two questions. The first is the key to solving this question was knowing to introduce the artifice $k=\dfrac{x}{y}$. However I don't really understand the justifications, assumptions or rules that allow me to assume $x$ varies directly with $y$. After all I cannot know what $x$ and $y$ are.

The second question is the problem statement says affirmatively the ratio is increased after subtracting $y$, but clearly the opposite happens for $1<k<2$. So either I'm wrong (and my calculations look correct to me) or the problem assertion is false.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For me, it seems like the problem statement is not well-written since, if $x = 1$ and $y = 0$, nothing changes. If I have $x = 2y$, then $x/(x - 2y)$ is simply undefined. Maybe there are restrictions on $x$ and $y$ that are skipped.

Comment: Are you given a specific *range* over which the solution is intended to hold? For instance, if we have $x \ge 2y \ge 0$, then both ratios have only positive (real) numbers in the numerator and denominator, and the assertion holds. Note that the second part of the restriction I'm guessing is equivalent to $k>2$.

Comment: Looks like a bad question. This is all I'm given. But it seems my computations are correct so that's good enough for me thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$Q = \frac{x+y}{x-y}$$
Take some A such that:
$$Q+A = \frac{x}{x-2y}$$
By solving for A, we have:
$$A=\frac{2y^2}{x^2-3xy+2y^2}$$
The numerator is always positive $\forall y\neq 0$. Similarly, the denominator is always positive except when $x \in [y,2y]$.
When $x=y$ or $x=2y$, we find that the fractions are undefined. When $x$ lies between $y$ and $2y$, $0>A$ and there will be a decrease in the fraction.

When $y=0$, we find that $A=0$ and hence there will be no change in the fraction.

Anyways, since $A>0$ for all other cases, we find that $$\frac{x}{x-2y} = Q+A>Q$$ when $x$ is not between or equal to $y$ and $2y$.

Comment: I just corrected the expression for $A$, which had a missing coefficient $2$  (typo). Answer is fine.